# i am getting this error while adding component- afterRender threw an error in 'System1:dataTableComponent' [e[Qi] is not a function]

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

[image]this is my js code-

```
import {LightningElement,wire, track} from 'lwc';

//import method from the Apex Class
import fetchAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/dataTableLWC.fetchAccounts';

// Declaring the columns in the datatable
const columns = [{
        label: 'View',
        type: 'button-icon',
        initialWidth: 75,
        typeAttributes: {
            iconName: 'action:preview',
            title: 'Preview',
            variant: 'border-filled',
            alternativeText: 'View'
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Name',
        fieldName: 'Name'
    },
    {
        label: 'Phone',
        fieldName: 'Phone'
    },

];

// declare class to expose the component
export default class DataTableComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track columns = columns;
    @track record = {};
    @track rowOffset = 0;
    @track data = {};
    @track bShowModal = false;
    @wire(fetchAccounts) parameters;

    // Row Action event to show the details of the record
    handleRowAction(event) {
        const row = event.detail.row;
        this.record = row;
        this.bShowModal = true; // display modal window
    }

    // to close modal window set 'bShowModal' tarck value as false
    closeModal() {
        this.bShowModal = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also provide your dataTableComponent.html file.

Comment: Can you show HTML also?